# Which version of scala should I release my library to?

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-2.10

When I was releasing for scala `2.9.x`, I simply had this line in my build.sbt:

```
crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.9.0", "2.9.0-1", "2.9.1", "2.9.1-1", "2.9.2")
```

But now, scala `2.10` is out, and I'm confused. My intuition was that I should have something like this:

```
crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.10.0")
```

But I noticed, that when I have scala version set to `2.10.0`, sbt searches for artifacts ending with `2.10`, not `2.10.0`. What's going on here? What version should I use?

**EDIT:** Also, if I do `publish-local`, the artifact also ends up being suffixed by "_2.10", instead of "_2.10.0".

Comment: i'm not sure, but these links should help: http://grokbase.com/t/gg/simple-build-tool/12bcfy6d5d/sbt-cant-compile-2-10-with-sbt https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/simple-build-tool/E0uSONFu7ew/b2k0AHTaw60J

Comment: @xhudik - don't think so - the library itself compiles completely normally.

Comment: did you check also comments, where states: crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.9.1", "2.10.0-RC1"), so in your case with different suffix e.g. "-RC5" - won't help?

Comment: @xhudik - Yes, I looked at them. I actually don't use suffixes, I just use the single version (2.10.0).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ["Scala 2.10.0 staged"](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scala-internals/3R7xTJhcN0I/969mjmP_-9AJ) thread says

> You can indeed simply cross version  against 2.10.

Comment: So I just publish only one artifact (2.10) and do not republish for later versions (2.10.1, 2.10.2, etc)?

Comment: [This post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-internals/3R7xTJhcN0I/_drJ3xQFv8AJ) on the same thread and some answers are interesting too